# Windows backup status?

Tags: windows-7, windows, backup

Is there a way to display Windows Backup status, other than opening the control panel item itself, or keeping an eye on the Action Center tray icon?

That is, is there a Gadget or even an API that shows the status? I'm looking for something that will show me the progress with a little more detail than the Action Center. Something more like Apple's Time Machine would be nice.

Any Google searches related to Windows Backup just seem to revolve around, well, backing up.

Comment: I am going with -NO- on this. I just ran a backup to a network location (windows 7-pro). I pulled up a DOS window and ran the other suggestion "wbadmin get status" and got nothing. That command only applies to a running (right now) backup. In researching the TechNet article mentioned (cc754015..) the "wbadmin get version" should have shown my last backup but didn't....possibly because the backup was not on the machine, I don't know. I have always had a friend with "robocopy". It can't do disk images but for a daily backup that might contain gigabytes of files that are unchanged it shines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see that you tagged Win7. I guess you're looking for wbadmin.

Have a look here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754015(v=ws.10).aspx

wbadmin get status